# How to create new folder in UNIX and copy ".log" files older than a specifice Date from some location to this Folder?

Tags: unix

I need to do some testing for that I want to make a temporary Directory in the Dev instance of my Unix server (Redhat Linux 6.9(64-bit)) and copy the files in that directory on which i want to perform testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do what you described:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p 'enter name of new folder: ' dir
if [ -e "$dir" ]; then
  echo 'A folder with the specified name already exists. Choose a different name.'
else
  mkdir "$dir"

  while read -r ; do
    mystring="${REPLY:2}"
    mystring="$(sed 's/\//_/g' <<<"$mystring")"
    cp "$REPLY" "$dir/$mystring"
  done < <(find / -mtime +30 -name '*.log' -type f)
fi
```

Where you can adjust the `find` command at the bottom to your needs:

- `+30` denotes files older than 30 days and
- `/` specifies the search directory you want to use to search for your log-files.

Here I assumed you want to search for log-files in the root directory `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'mkdir' command will make a directory. Depending on where you're making the folder, you may need super-user privileges.

You can use the 'find' command to get specific files, using the command line flags to filter. Here's an example with a date-specific flag. https://www.howtogeek.com/50211/delete-files-older-than-a-certain-date/ 
Instead of deleting your files ('rm'), you will want to move ('mv') or copy ('cp') your files to your new directory.